# 500: internal server error persists even after modifying file permissions on my wordpress site hosted on ipage

Tags: wordpress, cgi

I have a wordpress site hosted on ipage that started throwing 500 internal server error. I found the following in the cgi error log: 
20180526T212522: nandgeekcom.ipage.com/index.php
suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details.

I have checked the file permissions for scripts and folders and ensured they are 644 and 755 respectively but the problem still persists. Anyone with an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: I had the same issue. thanks for asking about it

Answer (score 1):

After the issue persisted even after checking all files and folders and ensuring they have the appropriate permissions, I decided to contact the ipage help desk and the problem was solved in a snap. The solution was to change the root permission (to 755) that had somehow been messed up. Since on the shared ipage hosting I don't have access to the root folder, changes had to be made in the backend. Error resolved!

Comment: I contacted them and solved the issue in 10 minutes. I used the live chat with issue type website layout/display problem.